# How can I prevent Kafka Connect JDBC Connector from reading from beginning / earliest messages, and instead read only the latest?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

## My Problem

I'm running Kafka Connect v2.12 in standalone mode, the the JDBC connector plugin v5.2.1.

I'm using JSON serialization, with the schema embedded in the payload.

Because the JDBC connector is fail-fast by design, if enters a `FAILED` state and stops processing messages if there is something wrong with a message received.

This would be okay if the JDBC connector only processed the latest messages. A bad message would make it crash, then it could be restarted, and pick up at the next (hopefully well-structured) message.

However, my JDBC connector has started* reading *all* historical messages when it starts up. I noticed in the startup logs that `auto.offset.reset` was set to `earliest`. This was strange because the default is `latest`, and `consumer.auto.offset.reset` was not set in my `worker.properties` file, to `earliest`, `latest`, or otherwise. Anyway, I edited my `worker.properties` file to explicitly set `consumer.auto.offset.reset` to `latest`, as shown below.

This change was successful in the sense that the startup logs now show `auto.offset.reset=latest`, but the connector still crashes on each startup as it tries to process a week-old message that was not well-formed JSON.

Which settings should I modify to make my Kafka Connect worker only pull the Kafka messages sent since the worker started up?

* *Until last week, the connector was only reading the latest messages. IDK whether I messed up something in the configuration, or someone else changed a global setting on the Kafka broker, but since last week, it's been reading all messages, starting from the earliest message, on each startup.*

---

## My Configuration

*`worker.properties`*

```
# This file was based from https://github.com/boundary/dropwizard-kafka/blob/master/kafka-connect/src/main/resources/kafka-connect/example.standalone.worker.properties

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/example.offsets

bootstrap.servers=kafka-0.kafka-headless.kafka:9092,kafka-1.kafka-headless.kafka:9092,kafka-2.kafka-headless.kafka:9092
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

rest.port=8083
rest.advertised.port=8083

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

# Prevent the connector from pulling all historical messages
consumer.auto.offset.reset=latest
```

---

## My Logs

For info, here's the list of historical messages. Take a guess at which message triggers the error, haha.

```
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"id"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"status"}],"optional":false,"name":"example_topic"},"payload":{"id":1337,"status":"success"}}
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"id"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"status"}],"optional":false,"name":"example_topic"},"payload":{"id":1337,"status":"success"}}
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"id"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"status"}],"optional":false,"name":"example_topic"},"payload":{"id":1337,"status":"success"}}
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"id"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"status"}],"optional":false,"name":"example_topic"},"payload":{"id":1337,"status":"success"}}
kafka_connect/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh \
      --broker-list kafka-0.kafka-headless.kafka:9092,kafka-1.kafka-headless.kafka:9092,kafka-2.kafka-headless.kafka:9092 \
      --topic example_topic
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"id"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"status"}],"optional":false,"name":"example_topic"},"payload":{"id":1337,"status":"success"}}
```

And the logs and error message that occurs on startup:

```
[2019-07-30 14:20:55,020] INFO Initializing writer using SQL dialect: PostgreSqlDatabaseDialect (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask:57)
[2019-07-30 14:20:55,021] INFO WorkerSinkTask{id=postgres_sink-0} Sink task finished initialization and start (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:302)
[2019-07-30 14:20:55,031] INFO Cluster ID: DPpxrPbVR5qwiI9vz_Gkkw (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata:273)
[2019-07-30 14:20:55,031] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=connect-postgres_sink] Discovered group coordinator kafka-2.kafka-headless.kafka:9092 (id: 2147483645 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:677)
[2019-07-30 14:20:55,033] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=connect-postgres_sink] Revoking previously assigned partitions [] (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:462)
[2019-07-30 14:20:55,033] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=connect-postgres_sink] (Re-)joining group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:509)
[2019-07-30 14:20:58,046] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=connect-postgres_sink] Successfully joined group with generation 884 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:473)
[2019-07-30 14:20:58,048] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=connect-postgres_sink] Setting newly assigned partitions [example_topic-0] (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:280)
[2019-07-30 14:20:58,097] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=postgres_sink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:177)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:178)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:513)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:490)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:321)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:225)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:193)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error: 
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:334)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$1(WorkerSinkTask.java:513)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'kafka_connect': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (byte[])"kafka_connect/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh \"; line: 1, column: 15]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'kafka_connect': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (byte[])"kafka_connect/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh \"; line: 1, column: 15]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:703)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3532)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2627)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:832)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:729)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readTreeAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4042)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2571)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:332)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$1(WorkerSinkTask.java:513)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:513)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:490)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:321)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:225)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:193)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem you are facing is that the setting "consumer.auto.offset.reset" is only applied for consumer groups that do not have a stored offset.

For example, let's say you have a consumer group that starts up for the first time. It looks for stored offsets and doesn't find them, so it looks at the "consumer.auto.offset.reset" setting. For this example, let's say it has been set to "earliest", so the consumer starts from the beginning of the log, processes a few messages and commits the offset (standard consumer operation). Next, you decide you don't want that, so you set "consumer.auto.offset.reset=latest" and restart. The consumer group again looks for its offsets and this time finds them because it has previously committed them, so it does not look at the offset setting (you have indeed set it to "latest" but since there are committed offsets that setting will be ignored).

It may be that for some reason, your original consumer was using "earliest" and now that you have committed offsets for you consumer group, you can't start at the latest.

If you want to fix this you can change the name of your consumer group (I'm not sure if KafkaConnect exposes this) or use the kafka-consumer-groups.sh script that comes with Kafka to set the offsets to "latest".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks you for your response. After deleting the consumer group, it stopped reading from the earliest. However, it the next bad message resulted in perpetual failures until I deleted the consumer group again. Is there a way to prevent the consumer from creating and joining a consumer group? I thought they were for distributed mode anyway, and I'm using standalone.

Comment: I'm not sure of a way around that. I would suggest (without knowing much about your application) that you handle the exception in your application code with a try-catch and just log the failures somewhere, that way your consumer never gets stuck on a record. Does that strategy work?

Comment: I was able to work around my problem by resetting the consumer group's offsets to the latest before starting my connector. The offsets can be reset with this command: `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server=my-broker:9092 --group connect-my-sink-connector --reset-offsets --to-latest --all-topics --execute`.
You can alternatively specify a single topic instead of all. A safer approach would be to get the current offset and increment it by 1. This would not work with multiple partitions, though.

Comment: @CameronHudson, to increment offset you can use `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` with `--shift-by` option.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Connect processing message contains from three phase (Sink Connectors):

1. Converting Message (using `Converter`)
2. Transforming message (using `Transformation`)
3. Writing message to external system

If message is invalid (can't be properly converted by `Converter`) you can set property to skip that message.

```
"errors.tolerance": "all",
"errors.log.enable":true,
"errors.log.include.messages":true
```

According to Kafka Connect configuration:

**errors.tolerance:**

> Behavior for tolerating errors during connector operation. 'none' is
>   the default value and signals that any error will result in an
>   immediate connector task failure; 'all' changes the behavior to skip
>   over problematic records.

**errors.log.enable:**

> If true, write each error and the details of the failed operation and
>   problematic record to the Connect application log. This is 'false' by
>   default, so that only errors that are not tolerated are reported.

**errors.log.include.messages:**

> Whether to the include in the log the Connect record that resulted in 
>   a failure. This is 'false' by default, which will prevent record keys,
>   values, and headers from being written to log files,  although some
>   information such as topic and partition number will still be logged.

Comment: I considered changing the error tolerance, but then how would I know if an application began sending malformed messages? Would I have to monitor and parse the logs for that kind of error message?

Comment: @CameronHudson, Unfortunately, yes. To distinguish it, you will have to parse the logs